# Excel formula referring to different sheet's cell not working

Tags: excel

I generated few addresses in Sheet1 in excel. Then, I tried to use those address to refer to Sheet2, excel is complaining that formula is not right. I did following: 
Sheet 1 has Addresses like:

```
     A       B       C       D       E 
1    $RD$834 $RE$834 $RF$834 $RG$834 $RH$834
2    $RD$835 $RE$835 $RF$835 $RG$835 $RH$835
3    $RD$836 $RE$836 $RF$836 $RG$836 $RH$836
4    $RD$837 $RE$837 $RF$837 $RG$837 $RH$837
5    $RD$838 $RE$838 $RF$838 $RG$838 $RH$838
```

Then, I tried in Sheet1.

```
=Sheet2!(Sheet1!A1)
```

But Excel complained this formula to be wrong.

Please help.

Comment: the correct way would be `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&Sheet1!A1)` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dirk commented, the correct way is to use INDIRECT function.